# How to replace characters that are before and after a block/paragraph?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is how I replace characters before and after a word:

```
el = el.replace(/"\b/g, '&ldquo;')
el = el.replace(/\b"/g, '&rdquo;')
```

What if I want to turn this:

````
```
This is a quote
```
````

Into this?

```
<quote>
This is a quote
</quote>
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the line after the closing sequence contains no text, right?

Comment: your text may contain ``` , right?

Comment: If you are sure that they won't happen unpaired use a simple counter `var counter = 0;
str.replace(/```/g, function() { return counter++ % 2 == 0 ? '<quote>' : '</quote>'; })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be another way to replace the starting and ending triple back-tick "```" to `<quote>` and `</quote>` respectively.

````js
const string = "```\nThis is a quote\n```";
const replacer = {
  '```\n': '<quote>\n',
  '\n```': '\n</quote>'
}

const str = string.replace(/```\n|\n```/gm, function(matched) {
  return replacer[matched];
})

console.log(str);
````

Comment: The alternation would match either one of them, it does not guarantee that it is between them. So if the string would be `const string = "```\nThis is a quote\n";` then that would also be replaced.

Answer (score 4):

You can match

````
^```
````

, lazy-repeat any character, until you get to another

````
^```
````

. The `^` at the beginning ensures that the three backticks are at the beginning of a line, and the `[\s\S]` below is a way to match *any character*, including linebreaks, which `.` does not do by default:

````js
function doReplace(str) {
  console.log(str);
  console.log(
    str.replace(/^```([\s\S]*?)^```/gm, '<quote>$1</quote>')
  );
}
doReplace("```\nThis is a quote\n```");
doReplace("```\nThis is a quote\nand there are some backticks in the text\nbut not ``` at the beginning of a line\n```");
````